# How to screenshot part of the screen under windows?

Tags: windows, screenshot

I would like to use mouse to select a part of a window under Windows and then take screenshot and save it as jpeg format. Is there such a functionality provided by Windows or some applications? I asked on behalf of a friend, as I am using Ubuntu exclusively and the built-in screen-shot in Ubuntu allows using mouse to select part of screen. Not sure which Windows edition he has, maybe  Windows 7 or XP. Thanks!

Comment: The "Screenshot utilities for Windows" link leads to 404 page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If they are on Vista or Win7, there is a new Snipping Tool that does exactly what you describe included. Just type "Snipping Tool" in the start menu search bar and it will open up.

Available in:
Snipping Tool is available only in the Home Premium, Professional, Ultimate, and Enterprise editions of Windows Vista/7.

**
I just ran across this little gem which adds a snipping tool for XP users.
http://xpsnipping.codeplex.com/

Comment: Should be accepted as you don't need a third party for this one :)

Comment: I think that Only some version of Windows 7 has snipping tool so we can't call it inbuilt for all. (coz I always miss it) :)

Comment: @Lamb I wasn't aware of this, but you are correct. I added the info to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Windows itself only provides the means to take screenshots of either the entire desktop, or a single application window. You need 3rd party software like [HyperSnap](http://www.hyperionics.com/) or [XnView](http://www.xnview.com/) for taking a screenshot of a screen section.

Answer (score 0):

[SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit) is one of the better screen capture tool with lots of features.

For a free solution, ALT-PrintScreen will capture your active window in windows to your clipboard, you can open Paint and save it to a JPG/PNG file.

Answer (score 0):

Word 2010 (possibly also 2007?) has a `Screenshot` button under Insert>Illustrations. You can select a window to capture or a part of the screen (screen clipping). Then right-click the screenshot and `Save As Picture...` to save it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Fast Stone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm), it has several capturing options, like full screen, full window (only the window you choose, even if it is not fullscreeen), ***rectangular region*** (which is what you want), and even freehand region and scrolling window, which is my favorite one, it can automatically capture any scrolling window in most programs, even if it has both vertical and horizontal scroll. That is specially useful for web pages or dialog windows. Other tools don't have that option and you would have to take several screenshots and then "paste" them together by yourself.

Also, you can trigger the capture via a small floating window, or via configurable keyboard shortcuts, and also you can copy the image directly to the clipboard, or to a (very nice) built in editor, or directly to a file, either asking for a name, or automatically naming it with several options like date, time, etc.

The current version is paid, but several versions before, it was completely free, so you can look for the last freeware version (it was version 5.3) and use it without any problem, it works pretty good! Of course the newer paid updates have other nice features, so its your call. Or i guess you can try the newer version for a trial period (not sure). Just check their site for more info.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I usually press PrintScreen, Win+R, "pbrush", Ctrl+V, then drag the image (align left top corner), select pen, scroll to the bottom right corner, drag bottom right corner to set size of image, finally save to BMP or PNG file with Ctrl+S.

It works everywhere since Windows 95, but I'm unsure if such a long sequence is a good answer to your question. But no third party tools involved, just Windows!